# RACObserve subscribeNext didn't execute when value of the observed item changed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reactive-cocoa

hello everybody I have an weird issue , I putted this code in my bind method :

```
[RACObserve(self.viewModel,contacts) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [self.contactsTableView reloadData];
}];
```

but when the contacts in my viewModel changed , the subscribeNext didn't execute !! , I checked if the value changed by debugging and it changed normally !!

this is where the value is changed in my view Model (Simplified) : 
I initilized it here :

```
- (instancetype)init {

    self.contacts = [[NSMutableArray <Contact *> alloc]init];

}
```

and changed here

```
  #pragma mark - load and filter methods
    - (RACCommand *)loadContactsCommand {
        ContactsNetworkManager *contactNetworkManager = [ContactsNetworkManager sharedManager];
        return [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
            return [[contactNetworkManager getAllContactsSignal] map:^id(NSMutableArray<Contact *> * value) {
                NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
                [value sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
                [_contacts removeAllObjects];
                [_contacts arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:value];
                return value;
            }];
        }];
    }

    #pragma mark - Actions
    - (void)loadContacts {
        [self.loadContactsCommand execute:nil];

    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find it , actually the solution is too simple , I had to use `self` rather than on an independent reference to the NSMutableArray object like `_` . In other words, it won't work if you do that , because the KVO established by RACObserve() is relative to the object you pass in as its first parameter (self, in this case), so only KVC-compliant mutations that pass through the observed object will trigger the observation notifications.